# Windows 7 graphics is laggy / jerky?

Tags: display

I have 1920x1080 LED display. I installed all drivers, games runs nicely. But if I minimize a window, as it goes down to the tray - its animation is laggy. Same as I restore the window. Same as I choose something from a combobox. Almost like Windows98 with no video drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the **[Windows Experience Index Benchmark](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/79177-windows-experience-index-reset.html)**.

When the benchmark completes, assuming your graphics adapter is up to it, Windows will enable *Desktop Composition* which is exactly what you need to enjoy smooth desktop animation.

After that, you can [tweak some extra settings](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127411-desktop-composition-enable-disable.html) if you want, but the above is the most important thing as it will make the Desktop Composition option available.